# Нужна ли запятая в выражении "обьясните почему"?

Tags: пунктуация

По просьбе подписчиков телеграм-канала администратор объяснил почему:

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ? А то не приняли почему-то.

Answer (score 1):

***Почему*** — придаточная часть, состоящая только из союзного слова. А придаточные, состоящие только из него, **не обособляются** — следовательно, запятая не нужна:

*По просьбе подписчиков телеграм-канала администратор объяснил почему: <...>*.

Но всë же таки, если автор хочет подчеркнуть союзное слово, он поставит запятую:

*По просьбе подписчиков телеграм-канала администратор объяснил, почему: <...>*.

Хотя ставить запятую перед придаточным, состоящим только из союзного слова, не рекомендуется обычно, поэтому запятая нежелательна.